# flutter firebase logout fail

Tags: firebase, flutter

state management is too difficult.

Login through firebase works normally and logout works well the first time.

However, if you log in and go to another screen, you cannot log out.

What went wrong?

- logout provider

'''

```
Future logout() async {
    await firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
```

'''

- Pages using logout

'''

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loginProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () async => await loginProvider.logout(),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
         
      
        ),
```

If I modify it like below, it works fine.
But I don't know if it's the right way.

'''

```
onPressed: () async => await loginProvider.logout().then(
                  (value) => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => Wrapper()))),
```

- Login Provider

'''

```
Future login(String email, String password) async {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      UserCredential authResult = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = authResult.user;
      setLoading(false);
      return user;
    } on SocketException {
      setMessage('No internet');
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      setMessage(e.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

'''

'''

- Login Screen

'''

```
Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                        color: Color(0xffe50815),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (this._formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            print('email : ${this.idCt.text}');
                            print('password : ${this.pwCt.text}');
                            await loginProvider.login(
                                this.idCt.text.trim(), this.pwCt.text.trim());
                          }
                        },
                        child: loginProvider.isLoading
                            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                            : Text("LOGIN",
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
```

'''

- provider

  ```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _init = Firebase.initializeApp();
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _init,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.error),
                Center(
                  child: Text('something went wrong!'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
                  value: AuthProvider(),
                ),
                StreamProvider<User?>.value(
                  value: AuthProvider().user,
                  initialData: null,
                  catchError: (_, err) => null,
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        MovieNowPlayingProvider()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (BuildContext context) => TvPopularProvider()),
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                home: SplashScreen(),
              ),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
  ```

  }
- Wrapper
  '''

  ```
  class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User?>(context);
    if (user != null) {
      return MainScreen();
    }
    return Authentication();
  }
  ```

  }

'''

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors are displayed.

Comment: Where is your LoginProvider defined?

Comment: Added code to the question.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain this part of your question: "Login through firebase works normally and logout works well the first time.
However, if you log in and go to another screen, you cannot log out." ?

Comment: 1. Login -> Login Success -> Main Page -> Logout -> Logout Success

2. Login -> Login Success -> Main Page -> Detail Page -> Main Page -> Logout -> Logout Failed

Do you understand?

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. Can you show which widget you wrapped your Provider with?

Comment: Added to the question. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, that's not it. Where did you introduce the Provider? For instance ```Provider(create: LoginProvider(), lazy: false, child: Widget())```.

Comment: edited. Is this what you want??

Comment: Yes, I thought the Provider wasn't scoped properly. I think the next code I'll need will be the `MainPage` to understand how it handles the navigation and that of `Wrapper` too.

Comment: Added Wrapper to the question.

Comment: Alright. Checkout my answer.

Comment: I just posted a new question on a different topic. Can you give me an answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410824/flutter-i-want-to-get-listint-as-int-one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

Using `.then` and then navigating to the wrapper is not wrong but you might want to restructure the `onPressed` code to this:

```dart
    onPressed: () async {
      await loginProvider.logout();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Wrapper())
      );
    },
```

Since you're using `async/await`, it's more consistent to use just that instead of combining it with `.then`.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply
However, notifyListeners(); The same is true for adding
Is it wrong to use loginProvider.logout().then() ?
Logout works fine with this method.

Comment: No, it's not wrong but since you're already listening to the current user in your `Wrapper`, this is the more correct method. Using `.then` and navigating manually will be like a repetition of what has already been implemented

Comment: I understood what you mean.
For now, let's use loginProvider.logout().then() . I'll fix it when I find out what the problem is.

Comment: Do you mean adding `notifyListeners()` did not solve it?

Comment: Yes using notifyListeners() does not solve it.

Comment: I saw the updated answer and modified the code. Works fine. thank you